# Add image fallback to WordPress video tag

Tags: css, wordpress, html5-video

I have a WordPress site that has the option for a video as the background, I need to add an image fallback for iPhone etc. Here is the tag, I am unsure of the syntax for the image fallback:

```
    [full_width_section color="#000000" video_webm="http://www.cms2020.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ATL_Background1080_Revise-2.webm" textcolor="#ffffff" video_ogv="http://www.cms2020.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ATL_Background1080_Revise.ogv" video_mp4="http://www.cms2020.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ATL_Background1080_Revise.mp4" ][space size="100"]
```

Comment: This looks like a shortcode for a WordPress theme rather than the HTML/CSS needed, so it will be difficult for someone to provide an answer. Most likely you'll need to do a CSS media-query which will set the video element to "display: none" and provide an alternative image. Depending on how the video is added to the site, the browser may still download it though